# Asked for work but no Job Letter yet

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, new-job

Currently on job hunting and I've had my interview already last week from Company A. The General Manager told me that the job spot is mine and he asked me I'd be interested for that.

Question:

- Would love to say "yes" however there hasn't been an offer yet (in terms of salary, position, and other benefit package). How should I ask properly (without offending him) that I'd like to see what's the offer first(before saying yes)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: @DavidK I'm not seeing the duplicate? The linked question is following up when they haven't had an affirmative response and are looking for one. This question is more trying to get more details about the job, that they haven't received

Comment: @Draken, sorry, you're right. I was going too fast and didn't read closely enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right not to *formally* accept until you see the job offer in writing. In these cases I say something like this:

> Thank you. I'd like to provisionally accept the post, subject to having a formal, written offer in place. After that, I can double check the offer, complete the necessary paperwork and hand my notice in to my current employer.

Answer (score 4):

> Would love to say "yes" however there hasn't been an offer yet

He asked if you would be interested, not if you would agree to unstated terms of employment.

If you are actually interested, simple say something like "Yes, I'm definitely interested! I'd love to talk about an offer and see if we can get together on terms."

Make sure you first have clear in your own mind what you want, as it will certainly be discussed.

Answer (score 1):

Say "Yes, I am interested. I am awaiting your offer", which is distinct from "Yes, I am accepting the offer".

That's all there is to it.

Let your prospective employer show their hand and show you what they've got in their hand.

Any onboarding procedure does not kick in until you've explicitly accepted the offer.